# Trying to calculate a flux integral

Tags: integration, vector-analysis

I'm trying to solve the flux integral of (using big letters for vectors). The vector field is the constant vector ${\bf A} = (1,2,3)$, andthe surface $S$ is $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$, with $z\geq 0$.

I want to calculate it as a flux integral, not using for example gauss. I'm trying to substitute $z$ for $\sqrt{1-x^2 -y^2}$, doing the cross product and then using polar coordinates but I can't get anywhere with that...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, the [outward flux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flux#General_mathematical_definition_.28surface_integral.29) of ${\bf A}=(1,2,3)$ through the surface $S$ is given by
$$\Phi:=\iint_{S} {\bf A}\cdot {\bf n}\ dS=$$
where $S$ is the upper unit hemi-sphere, ${\bf n}=(x,y,z)$ and $dS=\sqrt{1+f_x^2+f_y^2}dxdy$ with $z=f(x,y)=\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}.$
Then
$$\sqrt{1+f_x^2+f_y^2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}$$
and
$$\Phi=\iint_{S}\frac{x+2y+3\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}\ dx dy.$$
Now you may use the polar coordinates $x=\rho\cos\theta$ and $y=\rho\sin\theta$ with $dxdy=\rho d\rho d\theta$.

Note that there is also a shortcut which uses a symmetric argument.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I'm getting where you are, but I dont know where to go after that, am I supposed to split it up to three integrals after substituting?

Comment: @Stratbomber Yes. Split it!

Comment: ahh, thank you sir, now I see what you mean